how to find out which script sets variable during bash startup
When I log on to a certain machine, I get greeted with -bash: TMOUT: readonly variable
That means that somewhere in the depths of .bash_profile after untold levels of scripts sourcing other scripts, someone is setting TMOUT at least twice.
How do I find those two places?

See How do I find where the environment variables are defined in Linux.

thank you for that link ... I would not have derived that incantation ... turns out it was in /etc/profile :)
